# Visual studio 2015 project doesn't debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I move a project to another directory on my hard then i open this project using visual studio 2015 but i can't run this project

This exception is fired: 
[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFJRb.jpg)

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: have you build your solution after loading the project in VS? just clean and rebuild your solution once

Comment: So, which exception is raised?

Comment: You have enabled debugging of Microsoft's code.  The first message says that you are downloading the "symbols" (the PDB file(s)) for a Microsoft DLL.  The second one says "Hey, you wanted to look at this location on the stack (in NTDLL.dll) and I don't have the source for that.  Have you done a build clean and a full rebuild?  Are you seeing any errors (neither of those two images is an error)?  By the way, downloading symbols can take a long time (minutes) to complete the first time you run something like that.

Comment: As mentioned above, try do clean on your solution or delete your bin from your project folder. And then try rebuilding again

Comment: @Rahul 
i cleaned the solution and delete the bin folder and it didn't work also, this exception is fired:                        
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: Since you have decided to redact your source file names on the tabs, I will be unable to help. Also, debug the thing in the development folder. Moving stuff around is just asking for difficulties. You're trying to trace into the kernel, which is almost never the correct approach.

Comment: @3Dave 
I just move my project which is worked correctly without any problems to another partition on the hard disk but when i open this project from the new place this exception is fired :   An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: The PDB contains paths to the source files used to build the executable. You need to rebuild it if you moved it. (Or jump through flaming hoops involving symbolic links and other BS.) You can't just copy a project somewhere else and debug it without rebuilding.

Comment: @3Dave This is the first thing i made , clean the solution then make rebuilding Then make debugging but the same exception is fired

Comment: @3Dave The first form has been loaded but after that the exception is fired

Answer (score -1):

I just make this

**Tools->options->debugging->symbols**

Then **disable** Microsoft symbol server toolbox.

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsXiX.jpg)